# Exchange Get-DistributionGroupMember only displays member not other groups?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Im trying to display the list members of a distribution list.  There are only two, but one of them is actually an AD group.  When I run the script below from my workstation, I only see the single member and it also lists the entire property list whereas I just want the names, not every property of the list member.  If one of the members of the distribution list is itself a group, should its members be listed too?

```
#create session
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://MY-SPTMP-SERVER-URL/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos

#import session
Import-PSSession $Session

#query mailbox for alias
Get-DistributionGroupMember  "LIST-NAME"  # |  Format-List

#close session to release connection
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

Comment: `Get-DistributionGroupMember` will list AD groups if they are members, even if they are not email enabled. Are you sure the AD group is a member of the group you're looking at?

Comment: @Matt I also added a group that was not mail enabled to a DL for testing, and it does appear as a member (under RecipientType = Group).

Comment: @Kohlbrr Must have been a replication issue and my test was premature. So that is obviously not the issue then. Does `Get-ADgroupMember` have the same results? Is this a single domain? Maybe a trust issue?